# SQL Server : assign sequential number not working

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to execute the following code in order add sequential number to a table.

```
declare @myvar2 int
set @myvar2 = 1

update _TEST_DATA
set ID = @myvar2, @myvar2 = @myvar2 + 1;
```

When I run this, I get the same ID assigned to multiple rows in my table. Any suggestions?

I'm on SQL Server 2012

Comment: Why not just simply use a `SEQUENCE` that's available in SQL Server 2012 ....

Answer (score 0):

your increment needs to be done in its own `set` statement, NOT within the "set" clause of the `update` statement.

Try this:

```
update _TEST_DATA set ID = @myvar2
-- update is done, now increment
set @myvar2 = @myvar2 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row number to generate a sequence which increments by 1:

```
DECLARE @myvar2 INT;
SET @myvar2 = 1;

UPDATE  td
SET     ID = rn
FROM    _TEST_DATA td
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  ID,
                            @myvar2 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn
                    FROM    _TEST_DATA
                   ) a ON a.ID = td.ID;
```